# Changing background color in Google Map InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I want my InfoWindows in my Google Map implementation to have a black background color. "backgroundColor" is not an available option for InfoWindows. [See here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions).

I put a div tag in the content option with a black background and white text. However, that still renders with a white border.

Does anyone know a way to get a completely black background?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want complete control over the background but want the niceties of InfoWindow, then you can can use the [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox) from the [Google Maps Utility](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library) library.