# How to change the InfoWindow Background color

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm facing the problem,My google Map API showing default InfoWindow with background color white.I want change the White color to Black color.
REF CODE:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {


    infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
               //infoWindow.setStyle("background-color: red");


      });
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140803/styling-infowindow-with-google-maps-api ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution. This might not be a very elegant solution but it works fine if you don't have huge styling needs.

Since we can add our own html and style it. The marker background element is mainly the one which causes problem. For simple styling, instead of learning a whole new library, we can just remove that element using jQuery.

Insert this code in your init function and it will remove the background element.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    jQuery('.gm-style-iw').prev('div').remove();
});
```

Now, you are free to style your own divs. I styled the infoWindow in my project using this approach.
[image]

Hope it will help.

Comment: Does this still work? I implemented it in a newer version of the maps api and it doesn't seem to get invoked

Answer (score 8):

**This works for me** :

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track, 
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-d::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece,
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-c,
.gm-style .gm-style-iw-t::after { 
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Good, but there is still a reverse triangular in white at the bottom of infoWindow. So I also add the following 

.gm-style .gm-style-iw-tc::after {
    background: red;
}

Comment: Also add the following `.gm-style .gm-style-iw-tc::after {
  background: red;
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **InfoBox** here in [Google Maps Utility](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries).

This class behaves like google.maps.InfoWindow, but it supports several additional properties for advanced styling. An InfoBox can also be used as a map label.

You can also use **CSS** to style it. By checking this [tutorial](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html) and [this](http://artandlogic.com/2014/02/custom-google-maps-info-windows/), it will give you a sample code on how to do it.

Comment: The first link is broken, probably InfoBox [has been removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed).