# How to change the style with infowindow in google map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I need to change the style with infowindow in google map.
This is my code

```
 jQuery(function($) {
// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCcgSw6pOY1_1t4LpPQK360V0reIfLDOi0&callback=initialize"; 
document.body.appendChild(script);
});




function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    maxZoom: 4,
    minZoom: 2,
    navigationControl: false,
     scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    styles: [
        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#F7F7F7'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#F7F7F7'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#BCD9E1'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#b9b9b9'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#b9b9b9'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#BCD9E1'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#BCD9E1'}]
        }
      ]



};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);





// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['Capital Tower, ADNEC Complex Abu Dhabi', 24.299174,54.697277],
    ['Regional Office - Dubai - United Arab Emirates', 25.204849,55.270783],
       ['FUJAIRAH ', 21.756779, 58.842773],
     ['EGYPT', 28.822859, 26.674805],
    ['lybia', 30.123591, 16.303711],

];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent =[

    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>ABU DHABI HEADQUARTERS</h3>' +
    '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],


    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>'],

    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>'],

    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>'],

    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>'],
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow =   new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    var image = 'images/map-marker.png';
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(2);

    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
```

}

How can I change the background color or something with css, I tried this

```
.info_content{background-color: red}
```

But the result was like this. 
[image]

I need to change the whole window color. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the InfoWindow Background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456627/how-to-change-the-infowindow-background-color)

Comment: It says with infobox, Cant with infowindow ?

Answer (score 0):

you should look on html in your devtools and find class of parent element and after this just add style which you need to this class in your style.css file.

Comment: I dont get, Can you explain

Comment: I mean that you can find wrapper of you popup and set needed style. Something like this http://storage7.static.itmages.com/i/16/1024/h_1477304255_4717805_71b0ce02a2.png

Comment: That is a hidden div. You can see my code, there is no div like that